Knowledge base creation fails for Amazon Bedrock
I wrote a python code where I create Knowledge base based on the files stored in an S3 bucket. A bucket is created for each user which consists of files. The embeddings for each of these files are stored in the MonoDB and Vector based search is done for them. The following is my code for creating knowledge base:
bedrock_client = boto3.client('bedrock-agent', region_name='us-east-2')
def create_bedrock_knowledge_base(user_id, s3_bucket, collection_name):
    print('Creating Knowledge Base')
    response = bedrock_client.create_knowledge_base(
        clientToken=f"{user_id}-token".ljust(33, '0'),
        description=f"Creating knowledge base for user {user_id}",
        knowledgeBaseConfiguration = {
            'type': 'VECTOR',
            'vectorKnowledgeBaseConfiguration': {
                'embeddingModelArn': 'arn:aws:bedrock:us-east-2:aws:model/amazon.titan-embed-text-v2:0',
                'embeddingModelConfiguration': {
                    'bedrockEmbeddingModelConfiguration': {
                        'dimensions': 1024
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        name=f"KnowledgeBase_{user_id}",
        roleArn='<iam_arn>',
        storageConfiguration = {
            'mongoDbAtlasConfiguration': {
                'collectionName': collection_name,
                'credentialsSecretArn': '<secreat_Arn>',
                'databaseName': 'bedrock',
                'endpoint': 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<pwd>@<project>.<id>.mongodb.net',
                'fieldMapping': {
                    'metadataField': 'metadata',
                    'textField': 'text',
                    'vectorField': 'embedding',
                },
                'vectorIndexName': 'vector_index',
            },
            'type': 'MONGO_DB_ATLAS',
        }
    )
    return response['knowledgeBaseArn']

For this I get the error:
botocore.errorfactory.AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateKnowledgeBase operation: User: <iam_arn> is not authorized to perform: bedrock:CreateKnowledgeBase
I have tried S3 buckets and models in different regions, as well as same regions. But the same result. My I AM Role has AmazonBedrockFullAccess permission policy. Titan embedding model is also enabled.
Edit: I also manually added policy and tried it, still the same error. I tried manually with InvokeModel, it gave me error and when I added it, it was working.
